# Go: create map with array of maps

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a map with an array containing maps. My code:

Go:

```
func main() {
    m := map[string][]map[string]string{
        "photos": [{"a":"1"}, {"b": "2"}],
        "pictures": [{"a":"1"}, {"b": "2"}]
        }
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

What is wrong with this? Is this possible?

http://play.golang.org/p/UkokGzvtGL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No Square brackets
2. Always comma at the end of the line

http://play.golang.org/p/USm9kqDANn

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := map[string][]map[string]string{
        "photos":   {{"a": "1"}, {"b": "2"}},
        "pictures": {{"a": "1"}, {"b": "2"}},
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

Comment: thanks. I'm actually trying to obtain a value from a flickr api json response. the result looks like this: { "photos": { "page": 1, "pages": "107553", "photo": [
      { "id": "15035296541", "owner": "51816274@N05",}]}. how do I access id?

Comment: like this: result["photos"]["photo"][0]["id"]

Comment: thanks. when I do that, I get a panic error saying the index is out of range. I did: res := make(map[string]map[string][]map[string]string); json.Unmarshal(body, &res); photourl, _ := res["photos"]["photo"][0]["url_m"]

Comment: then it means that "photo" array has no values. You should check the len() of the array before accessing it

Comment: You're really better off using a struct: http://play.golang.org/p/vRRZc8L5rL -- not sure why everyone tries to do this the hard way.